# imgproxy on non default port

Tags: linux, docker, centos, imgproxy

Ive installed imgproxy (https://docs.imgproxy.net/installation) on docker on a centos server.

Using

```
docker run -p 2096:2096 -it darthsim/imgproxy
```

to start it still starts the server on 8080:

> INFO    [2021-09-01T10:13:25Z] Starting server at :8080

What is a correct way of starting imgproxy on a non default port (in my cas 2096)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docker run command the ports describe a mapping from the host to the container port. (which by default is `8080:8080`)

So, to map your host's port 2096 to the container's 8080 use

```
docker run -p 2096:8080 -it darthsim/imgproxy
```